# Xml subsection in my SOAP request is getting XML characters escaped

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP Web interface I want to interact with. There is a section of the SOAP Request that should be like the following:

```
<postCommand>
    <ServiceData>Data</ServiceData>
</postCommand>
```

I built the Web Reference from the WSDL file and got a postCommandClient that let me input the XML data as a string. I then attempted the actual POST request and saw in Fiddler that my output came out more like this:

```
<postCommand>
&lt;ServiceData&gt;Data &lt;/ServiceData&gt;&#xD;
<postCommand>
```

Clearly there is some kind of escaping going on here, but I'm uncertain as to why.

Here is the relevant part of the WSDL:

```
      <xs:element name="postCommand">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="dataXml" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

The relevant piece of code:

```
                            var postXml = new SoapWebService.postCommand
                        {
                         //At this point it's all properly formatted XML as a string
                            dataXml = soapEnvContent 
                        };

var resp = apiClient.postCommand(postXml)
```

I haven't run into this escaping problem before, so I'm uncertain how to proceed. Is there a way to avoid the XML escaping?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you to use `CDATA`. Actually, this was a wrong answer. Because, CDATA is not a part of XML logical structure. You can use CDATA in html or DOM structure maybe but as a matter of fact CDATA doesn't decode anything. It is just a sign for browsers or another 3rd part applications. 
So,

```
<postCommand>
&lt;ServiceData&gt;Data &lt;/ServiceData&gt;&#xD;
<postCommand>
```

This format is correct encoding for SOAP. You should just decode it in responses. You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` for this purpose.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the CData tags were escaped as well.